# While loop without content

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm writing a Python program for a guessing game and the current way I'm implementing the main loop works, but it *feels* wrong:

```
# Guess Loop
while not(guess(ans)):
    pass
```

It will work but I was wondering if this is bad practice (I assume it is).

Comment: I'd avoid this. Instead I'd do `while True: if guess(ans): break`

Comment: I don't find anythign wrong with the original; perhaps my ancient coding idioms are warping my impressions.

Comment: The two code slices function identically (and likely get abstracted away by some compiler to the same bytecode). I find my snippet easier to read. "Loop forever, call this function each time, break when it succeeds" as opposed to "Loop while the negation of this function is true."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer

```
while True:
    if guess(ans):
        break
```

but your code

```
while not(guess(ans)):
    pass
```

functions identically. It may even be slightly more performant!

```
from dis import dis
from random import choice

def foo(): return choice([True, False])  # flip a coin

# My code
def bar1():
    while True:
        if foo(): break

# Your code
def bar2():
    while not(foo()):
        pass

>>> dis(bar1)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              12 (to 14)

  3     >>    2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foo)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        2
              8 BREAK_LOOP
             10 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
             12 POP_BLOCK
        >>   14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(bar2)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              10 (to 12)
        >>    2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foo)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        10

  3           8 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   10 POP_BLOCK
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Your snippet can omit the "`BREAK_LOOP`" there, which might improve performance. Of course the `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` might also be slightly harder than the `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`. Or vice-versa.

Regardless, they function identically. Use whichever one you like. I prefer the look of "Loop forever, and if `guess(ans)` is true, break" to "Loop until the negation of `guess(ans)` is false."

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing against this in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's de facto coding standard. This is exactly what while loops are for.

I think you're concerned because the while loop is empty, but in a non-trivial program it wouldn't be, and you'd have something to put there.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to handle this idea - any issues with looping (specifically the bugs that can occur of a while(true) loop) wouldn't be true here, but maybe would come up in other languages, which is maybe what gave you pause.